# Where is local data defined inside a function stored at startup

Tags: c, function, struct, compilation, stack

I understand that global data will be stored in the .BSS or .data segment.

If I have data such as a structure defined inside a function however, this structure will only get placed on the stack when the function is called.

Where does the compiler store this data at startup tho before the function is called? 
I know that compilers generate different assembly code depending on the target and calling conventions etc. , but generally, wouldn't this local structure have to be stored somewhere first so that the compiler knows how to put it on the stack when the function is called? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean that the local variable is initialized, then the initialization does have to be stored somewhere (quite possibly the data segment), unless it's very simple (all bytes zero, perhaps).  But this is part of why C doesn't set local (automatic) variables to a pre-determined value when the function is called; it takes time/space to handle the initialization which would often be overwritten anyway.

Comment: But how does it know to put the structure there everytime it is called, the size, offsets to members etc. ? Isn't this information stored somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is stored somewhere — I suggested it might be the data section, but I've not dissected the generated assembly language on your machine to see how it's done; nor, indeed, have I checked on my machine).  It's the job of the compiler/linker to make sure it happens correctly.  The standard doesn't mandate how it must be done; it just mandates that the effect must be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

In case of global variables (also static local):
The compiler accesses global variables as memory parts of certain address and size. The address is initially a placeholder (much like the name of the variable). The size is implicit, depending on which kind of access the compiler has chosen in assembly/machine-code. The linker/loader is aware of the size, it makes sure that the next variable is not overlapping.
The address placeholder gets replaced during linking (e.g embedded, static, execute-in-place) or loading (e.g. programs on a PC, Apps).

In case of local variables:
The "address" value, which gets written into the placeholder, is relative, an offset on "top" of the stack position at the time of starting the function.
It is otherwise determined like the values for the global placeholders. The position on the stack is influenced by which variable is accessed, optionally with a sub-offset for struct members. The actual address is determined as the stack position (i.e. value of stack pointer) plus the relative offset found in the placeholder.

The placeholders are actually lists of offsets, stored in a binary (e.g. a program.exe) along with the actual binary code. Something like "when you have decided where this variable is found in memory, then write the address in all the places within code which are listed here: ...". Writing to these places will for example put a meaningful value in a byte which during execution will be interpreted as a literal offset to a relative "MOV" assembler instruction; relative to e.g. a section pointer to start of BSS section.

So in short, the address information is in the lists of placeholders. These lists migth not be found in memory at all, or not at execution time. Once the program is loaded (including filling in the placeholders) these lists are not needed anymore.
The size information is part of the code (e.g. using 8bit access or 32bit access) and it is part of the layout of variable locations. Each gets accessed far enough behind the previous variable.

So, even shorter, the information you are looking for is half hidden and half not in memory at all during execution.

I assume that your question was not about the value inside variables. Just to cover it: The value gets initialised to either 0, a constant initialisation value or, special cases, not at all, keeping whatever is in the memory at startup. The init values are found in sections which are basically lists of constants. Where exactly the constant for a given variable is found is similar to the placeholders.
In case of local variables, the compiler usually does not initialise, but can be configured to write 0 (which is kind of "expensive"). That is why it is good practice to init variables before using them. Local variables with explicit initialisation are of course initialised during stack frame setup.